# Proving a set is closed and dense

Tags: general-topology

> Let $E=C(I,\mathbb{R})$ where $I=[0,1]$. Consider two norms on $E$ defined for all $f\in E$:
>   $$
> \|f\|_{\infty}=\max_{t\in I}|f(t)|,\qquad 
> \|f\|_1=\int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|\, \mathrm dt.$$
>   Define $A$ to be the set of all functions $f\in E$ such that $f(0)=0$.
>   Prove that $A$ is closed with the norm $\|f\|_{\infty}$ and is dense in $E$ with the norm $\|f\|_1$.

For the first part, I try to use the fact that $A$ is closed iff every convegent series in $A$ has its limit in $A$.

Let $(g_n)_n$ be a convergent serie in $A$ and  $g$ is its limit. Since $g_n$ is continuous, we have $g$ is continuous and  $\lim_{n\to\infty} g_n(0)=g(0)=0$ thus $g\in A$.

I didn't use the definition of the norm $\|f\|_{\infty}$ to get the conclusion. Were I wrong somewhere?

For the second part, I have no idea. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "Since $g$ is continuous, we have that $g$ is continuous" and *here* you used the definition of the norm $\lVert\cdot \rVert_\infty$... i.e., you used the fact that $g_n\to g$ in the supremum norm (uniform convergence).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part, your argument regarding the continuity of $g$ can be left out.  We already know that $g$ is continuous because we assume $g \in E$.

What you need for the first part is that convergence with respect to the norm $||\cdot||_\infty$ is *uniform convergence* and uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence.  Show that this implies that $A$ is closed.

For the second part, you have to show that for $f \in E$  arbitrary,  there exists a $g \in A$ such that $||f - g||_1$ is small (as small as you like).  The function $g$ is required to be continuous and to satisfy $g(0) = 0$.  You have to think:  how can you alter your given function $f$ without changing it on very much of the interval, so that the changed function takes the value $0$ at $0$.  Can you find a function $\varphi \in E$ such that $\varphi(x) = 1$ on most of the interval, $0 \le \varphi(x) \le 1$ on all of the interval, and $\varphi(0) = 0$. If so, take $g(x) = f(x) \varphi(x)$.